# WIX Application pool incorrect after install or Upgrade

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

In our WIX installer we create several application pools for various components, however our .net 1.1 application pool always ends up being on .net 2.0 after the install has finished.

This causes us to manually fix the application pool that we have created back to 1.1 after each install and upgrade.

My question is is there a way around it, to get the installer to register it correctly as a 1.1 application pool rather than changing it to the 2.0 application pool?

Our code for creating the application pools:

```
<Component Id ="WebApps.Component" Guid="{5F518238-F564-43ff-A249-F87C23E02B52}">
            <CreateFolder />
            <iis:WebAppPool
               Id="V1WebAppPool"
               Name=".Net 1.1 App Pool"
               ManagedRuntimeVersion="v1.1"
               Identity="networkService">
            </iis:WebAppPool>
            <iis:WebAppPool
               Id="V2WebAppPool"
               Name=".Net 2.0 App Pool"
               ManagedRuntimeVersion="v2.0"
               Identity="networkService">
            </iis:WebAppPool>
            <iis:WebAppPool
               Id="V4WebAppPool"
               Name=".Net 4.0 App Pool"
               ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"
               Identity="networkService">
            </iis:WebAppPool>
         </Component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [Creating a WIX Installer for ASP.NET Web Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application)

The code section for the asp.net version

```
    <!-- Switch ASP.NET to version 2.0 -->
    <CustomAction Id="MakeWepApp20" Directory="MYWEBWEBSITE" 
      ExeCommand="[ASPNETREGIIS] -norestart -s W3SVC/1/ROOT/[WEB_APP_NAME]" 
      Return="check"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="MakeWepApp20" After="InstallFinalize">
               ASPNETREGIIS AND NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

It's the CustomAction that sets the version of ASP, you could create a condition that will run the right CustomAction to Switch between versions.  Here's a [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435) to switch versions.

HTH

Comment: That is the problem, I'm doing something very similar to this, however the .net 1.1 app pool that we have created still ends up being a .net 2 app pool. I have already checked things like .net 1.1 being installed and registered etc before the install.

Comment: Did you log the installation, to see if the condition was meet for the right CA to be used ?

Comment: Did you see this http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx

Comment: Thank you, it seems that one of our web apps didn't get registered correctly.